# How do I add TwoLineIconListItem in a builder using a method in python kivymd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to make an android application using kivy, kivymd in python. In

 that app I want to add a music player which will automatically find

 all the music files and then it will add all that files as a

 OneLineIconListItem, and when we click on it the music will be played

 as per the title of the OneLineIconListItem text I mean that

 as a normal offline android music player which shows all the file(music name) and when we

 click on that it will play the song my code is -:

```
   from kivy.lang import Builder
import os
from kivymd.app import MDApp

helper_string = """
Screen:
    name: "Music_Player"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
        title: "Toolbar"
        elevation: 10

        MDLabel:
        text: "Music_Player" 
"""


class MusicApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen

    def getting_all_music_files(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/'):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                    required_file = file
                    the_location = os.path.abspath(required_file)
```

If you want to get the file location then just print the_location and set the directory in my case it is in C:/

 Now, what I want is to add a for loop that takes all the locations and then add it as a list in my screen:
BoxLayout:

 But I am not able to figure out that how to use a for loop for this that add the location OneLineIconListItem to my app and when we will click on it it will play the song..

 I am new to programming so please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: container
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}")
            )

Test().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it literally helped me a lot and now I can move on